# Problemas ao tentar subir projeto no Bitbucket com o Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, github, bitbucket

Quero subir meu projeto com git no repositório do Bitbucket pelo Netbeans, sempre que tento enviar da o seguinte erro:

O repositório remoto contém commits não mesclados na ramificação local.
Abra a saída para ver mais informações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Como resolver?

Comment: Tente dar um git pull antes de fazer o push

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente isso, precisava puxar os arquivos que já tinha no repositório pra só depois subir.

Comment: @EmersonVieira, como descobriu o problema do AP, o que acha de fornecer uma resposta para a pergunta? :)

Comment: ok, @Dherik. Vou colocar uma resposta. :)